# Need help creating the Data Model for a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I've had some experience with some self projects in Rails and I'm having some trouble creating the data model for this specific scenario. Basically, there are many users, each of whom can play many instruments, and for each user/instrument pairing, there is a certain skill level associated with it.

For example, Joe can play saxophone with skill level 5, clarinet with skill level 2, and trumpet with skill level 3. Bob can play trombone with skill level 1, saxophone with skill level 4, and clarinet with skill level 5.

I understand how to make this with traditional SQL, but I really want to be able to take advantage of the Rails ActiveRecord features (so, in theory, I could do something like this:

```
@users = User.all
@users.each do |user|
  user.instruments do |ins|
  puts ins.level  #The current user's skill level on a particular instrument
  end
end
```

How do I create the migrations/models to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the models are basically:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :instrument_skills
  has_many :instruments, through: :instrument_skills
end

class InstrumentSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instrument
end

class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

that said you could create the models like::

```
rails g model User name:string
rails g model InstrumentSkill instrument_id:integer user_id:integer level:integer
rails g model Instrument name:string
```

then your generated migration probably look like:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t| 
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end 
  end 
end

class CreateInstruments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :instruments do |t| 
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end 
  end 
end

class CreateInstrumentSkills < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :instrument_skills do |t| 
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :instrument_id
      t.integer :level
      t.timestamps
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Would I need to create a separate Level model also?

Comment: Could you also explain what the "through" keyword does? It's a little confusing...

Comment: That DB design of my answer has nothing to do with Rails specifically. It is your use case mapped to tables and associations. A user has multiple skills (like playing piano, drums or whatever) and therefore also is associated with multiple instruments by its skills (with a certain level). And back to Rails: that is why it is (in Rails words) a has many through association. A user has many instruments through skills. And that is exactly how Rails named the option: 'through'.